# Printing black slash with quotes

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, printf

Printing a variable

```
var vin = "{\"method\": \"vinotestMethod\"}"
print(vin)
```

Gives me the output:

> {"method": "vinotestMethod"}

But I need the output like:

> {\"method\": \"vinotestMethod\"}

how can we do it in Swift?

Comment: Please accept answers that solve your questions. You haven't done this on ANY of your questions so far.

Answer (score 1):

To escape the backslash, triple it:

```
var vin = "{\\\"method\\\": \\\"vinotestMethod\\\"}"
print(vin)
```

Will print:

> {\"method\": \"vinotestMethod\"}

Comment: @Vinod remember to accept questions that answer your questions. Looking at your question history you haven't accepted ANY of the answers to your questions. Please do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create `JSON` then instead of writing by your self using `\` you need to use `JSONSerialization` like this.

**Swift 3**

```
let dic = ["method" : "vinotestMethod"] //Add other key-value pair that you want
if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: .prettyPrinted) {
    let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print(str)
    //If you doesn't want `\n` with String
    print(str?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: ""))
}
```

**Swift 2.3 or lower**

```
let dic = ["method" : "vinotestMethod"] //Add other key-value pair that you want
if let data = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dic, options: .PrettyPrinted) {
    let str = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(str)
    //If you doesn't want `\n` with String
    print(str?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: ""))
}
```